# redirect new tab to a url using firefox addon-sdk

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a restartless firefox extension using firefox addon-sdk.I want whenever a newtab is opened it should load the desired url.In overlay extension it is done using setting the pref branch browser.newtab.url to that url.Can i set the pref 'browser.newtab.url' in addon-sdk?

Comment: a lot of people oding this. a lot of ppl asked in the last month. search out `http-on-modify-request` under tag [tag:firefox-addon-sdk] ull get what ur looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i set the pref 'browser.newtab.url' in addon-sdk?

Yes, you can. Take a look to [preferences/service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/preferences_service) module.